# Logging all http request with mitmproxy inline script

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I'm trying to log every http site with mitmproxy but my in-line script is giving this error **TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'flow'** Here is a preview of my code. I do have my proxy set up correctly and the httplogs.txt file on the same directory as the in-line script but I don't understand what is wrong in this function.

```
import sys

def request(context,flow):
    f = open('httplogs.txt', 'a+')
    f.write(flow.request.url + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming you're on an updated (Jan 2017) version*

***tl;dr***

remove `context` from method signature

---

7 months ago mitmproxy removed ***context*** from the ***response*** method:

https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/commit/c048ae1d5b652ad4778917e624ace217e1ecfd91
[image: Da commit]

**So the updated example script is here:**

https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/1.0.x/examples/simple/add_header.py

```
def response(flow):
    flow.response.headers["newheader"] = "foo"
```

Comment: sounds similar experience to mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, that fixed it!

This is my updated snippet for logging request & response headers:

```
def response(flow):
    print("")
    print("="*50)
    #print("FOR: " + flow.request.url)
    print(flow.request.method + " " + flow.request.path + " " + flow.request.http_version)

    print("-"*50 + "request headers:")
    for k, v in flow.request.headers.items():
        print("%-20s: %s" % (k.upper(), v))

    print("-"*50 + "response headers:")
    for k, v in flow.response.headers.items():
        print("%-20s: %s" % (k.upper(), v))
        print("-"*50 + "request headers:")
```